# logic causing variable not to pass to function

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, logic

I am having an issue getting a variable set to pass to a function properly. The frustrating part is that until yesterday this code has been working properly for a good 4 months of weekly use.

Below is the code, removing the dims and parts of the code that will not help resolve this issue.

```
    Sub Combined_15_and_45()
    
    'Dim Iteration Variables
    'Dim tracking variables    
    'Dim range variables    
    'Dim Invoice Value Variables    
    'Dim Email body variables
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set WithTerms = Sheet4
    Set APEmail = Sheet7
    
        With wb
            With WithTerms
                lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
                elrow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                CalcDate = .Cells(1, 3).Value
                i = 1
                'loop through looking for times when cell above is different *Store i Instance
                'loop through looking for times when cell below is different *Store i as EndInstance
                'Specifically searching for changes in account number
                
                For i = 4 To lrow
                    h = i - 1
                    j = i + 1
                    
                        Set rng = .Cells(i, 5)
                        Set RngUp = .Cells(h, 5)
                        Set RngDwn = .Cells(j, 5)
                        
                        'this is where vendor account changes.
                        If rng.Value <> RngUp.Value Then
                            instance = i
                        End If
                        
                        'Check if invoice for the line is extreme past due *Store i as MaxOvrDue
                        If .Cells(i, 10).Value <= .Range("C1").Value - 45 Then
                                MaxOvrDue = i
                        End If
                        
                        'check if invoice for line is +15 day overdue, less than 45 * Store i as MidOvrDur
                        If .Cells(i, 10).Value <= .Range("C1").Value - 15 Then
                            If .Cells(i, 10).Value >= .Range("C1").Value - 44 Then
                                If MidOvrdue = 0 Then
                                    MidOvrdue = i
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                        
                        'Check if Invoice for line is 15+ days overdue (Minimum) *Store i as Ovrdue
                        If .Cells(i, 10).Value < .Range("C1").Value Then
                            If .Cells(i, 10).Value <= .Range("C1").Value - 14 Then
                                OvrDue = i
                            End If
                        End If
                        
                        'figure values for the totals of each section
                        If rng.Value <> RngDwn.Value Then
                            EndInstance = i
                            TotalOverdue = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("K:K"), .Range("E:E"), .Cells(instance, 5), .Range("J:J"), "<" & (.Range("c1") - 15))
                            XtrmOverdue = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("K:K"), .Range("E:E"), .Cells(instance, 5), .Range("J:J"), "<" & .Range("C1") - 44)
                            MidTotalOverdue = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(.Range("K:K"), .Range("E:E"), .Cells(instance, 5), .Range("J:J"), "<" & .Range("C1") - 15, .Range("J:J"), ">=" & .Range("C1") - 45)
                            
                            
                            
                            
                                If OvrDue = 0 And MaxOvrDue = 0 And MidOvrdue = 0 Then
                                    Else:
                                        'begin building Extremely Overdue Invoice Text
                                        If MaxOvrDue <> 0 And MidOvrdue = 0 Then
                                                                                                                                
                                            **Set XtrmTblRng = .Range(.Cells(instance, 7), .Cells(MaxOvrDue, 11))**
                                            
                                        End If
                                        
                                        If OvrDue <> 0 And MidOvrdue <> 0 Then
                                            If MaxOvrDue = 0 And OvrDue <= MidOvrdue Then
                                                
                                                **Set MidTblRng = .Range(.Cells(MidOvrdue, 7), .Cells(OvrDue, 11))**                                                
                                                'Begin building ONLY overdue email text
                                                    
                                                                           
                                                Else:
                                                'begin building segments to add to extreme overdue email
            
                                                    **Set XtrmComboTblRng = .Range(.Cells(instance, 7), .Cells(OvrDue, 11))**
                                                
                                            End If
                                        End If
                               
                                If OvrDue <> 0 Then
                                        'Generate the email
                                        With OutMail
                                            .To = eAddy
                                            
                                            'Figure out which email to send
                                            
                                            If MaxOvrDue <> 0 And MidTotalOverdue <> 0 Then
                                                .HTMLbody = StrBodyXtrm & RangetoHTML(XtrmComboTblRng, CalcDate) & ComboStrBody2 & StrBody4

                                                Else
                                                If MaxOvrDue <> 0 And MidOvrdue = 0 Then
                                                    .HTMLbody = StrBodyXtrm & RangetoHTML(XtrmTblRng, CalcDate) & StrBody2 & StrBody4

                                                Else:
                                                    .HTMLbody = StrBodyOverdue & RangetoHTML(MidTblRng, CalcDate) & StrBody3

                                                End If
                                            End If
                                            .display
                                        End With
                                        With Application
                                            .EnableEvents = True
                                            .ScreenUpdating = True
                                        End With
                                    End If
                                End If
                            'clear variables when changing vendor IDs
                        End If
                    Set rng = .Cells(j, 5)
                    Next i
                End With
            End With

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(TblRng, CalcDate)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook
    Dim tRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim CalcDate2 As Double
    Dim TempDate As Double
    
    
    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to paste the data in. This is where I am getting errors all the sudden
    **TblRng.Copy**
'manipulate the data from table to fit needs and past into email.
End Function
```

Essentially this is trying to sort through stack of invoices and determine which email format to use.
Invoices aged 45+
Invoices aged 15-45+
Invoices aged 15-44
I am running into an issue with the email determining a different email format should be used than the TblRng variable that has been built to pass to the function. I just cant seem to find my logic error.

I have been banging my head against a wall for a few days now trying to fix this with no luck. Any help you can give will make you a hero in my eyes!

Thank you

Comment: This line  might be the problem `If maxOvrDue = 0 And OvrDue <= midOvrDue Then`.  I can't see how `OvrDue` can ever be less than `midOvrDue` and will only be equal if there is only one record in the 15-44 band.  With 2 records in the range it will goto the Else and use the combo option. The solution I think is to just use `If maxOvrDue = 0 Then`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your logic is with this line

```
If maxOvrDue = 0 And OvrDue <= midOvrDue Then
```

If there are no >45 lines (maxOvrDue = 0) then at the first occurance of a >15 line
`midOvrDue` and `OvrDue` will be the same. On subsequent >15 lines `OvrDue` will
be greater than `midOvrDue`. So the above will be true for 1 and false for 2 or more
lines in the 44-15 range. With 2 or more the default Else option will then `Set XtrmComboTblRng` not `MidTblRng`.

Later because `maxOvrDue = 0` the email `.HTMLbody` uses `RangetoHTML(MidTblRng, CalcDate)`.
The remedy would be to just use `If maxOvrDue = 0 Then`.

You could set an email type within the same logic as used to set the ranges so the mismatch can't occur. Here is an example of how to do that

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Combined_15_and_45()
    
    Dim WithTerms As Worksheet, APEMail As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, tblRng As Range
    Dim lrow As Long, elrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim instance As Long, maxOvrDue As Long, midOvrDue As Long
    Dim CalcDate As Date, DaysLate As Integer, EmailFormat As Integer
    Dim has45 As Boolean, has15 As Boolean
    Dim acc As String
    Dim TotalOverdue As Currency
    Dim XtrmOverdue As Currency, MidTotalOverdue As Currency
    
    Set APEMail = Sheet7
    elrow = APEMail.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    ' for debugging
    Dim fso, ts
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' scan down sheet
    Set WithTerms = Sheet4
    With WithTerms
        lrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row 'Row E
        CalcDate = .Range("C1").Value
                
        For i = 4 To lrow
                     
            'this is where vendor account changes.
            Set rng = .Cells(i, 5) ' E Account
            If rng.Value <> rng.Offset(-1).Value Then
                acc = rng
                instance = i
                maxOvrDue = 0
                midOvrDue = 0
                XtrmOverdue = 0
                MidTotalOverdue = 0
            End If
                        
            ' check days overdue
            DaysLate = DateDiff("d", .Cells(i, "J").Value, CalcDate)
            If DaysLate >= 45 Then
                maxOvrDue = i
                XtrmOverdue = XtrmOverdue + .Cells(i, "K")
            ElseIf DaysLate >= 15 Then
                midOvrDue = i
                MidTotalOverdue = MidTotalOverdue + .Cells(i, "K")
            End If
           
            ' is this last for account
            If rng <> rng.Offset(1) Then
                                  
                TotalOverdue = XtrmOverdue + MidTotalOverdue
                Debug.Print vbCr & acc & " Total", XtrmOverdue, MidTotalOverdue, TotalOverdue
                has45 = maxOvrDue > 0
                has15 = midOvrDue > 0
               
                If has45 Or has15 Then
                    If has45 And has15 Then
                        EmailFormat = 1
                        Set tblRng = .Range(.Cells(instance, 7), .Cells(midOvrDue, 11))
                        Debug.Print "+45 and +15", tblRng.Address
                        ' begin building segments to add to extreme overdue email
                        
                    ElseIf has45 Then
                        EmailFormat = 2
                        Set tblRng = .Range(.Cells(instance, 7), .Cells(maxOvrDue, 11))
                        Debug.Print "+45 only", tblRng.Address
                        ' begin building Extremely Overdue Invoice Text

                    ElseIf has15 Then
                        EmailFormat = 3
                        Set tblRng = .Range(.Cells(instance, 7), .Cells(midOvrDue, 11))
                        Debug.Print "+15 only", tblRng.Address
                        ' begin building ONLY overdue email text
                    End If
            
                    ' select email format
                    Dim body As String
                    Select Case EmailFormat
                        Case 1
                            body = "strBodyXtrm" & RangetoHTML(tblRng, CalcDate) & "ComboStrBody2 & strBody4"
                        Case 2
                            body = "strBodyXtrm" & RangetoHTML(tblRng, CalcDate) & "strBody2 & strBody4"
                        Case 3
                            body = "strBodyOverdue" & RangetoHTML(tblRng, CalcDate) & "strBody3"
                    End Select

                    ' create html file for checking
                    Set ts = fso.createTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & acc & ".html", 1)
                    ts.write body
                    ts.Close

                    'Generate the email
                    'With outmail
                         '.To = eAddy
                         '.HTMLbody = body
                         '.display
                    'End with
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(tblRng, CalcDate) As String

    Dim s, rw As Range, cell As Range, pre As String
    pre = "<pre>TblRng=" & tblRng.Address(External:=1) & "</pre>"

    s = "<tr align=""center"" bgcolor=""#ddddff"">" & _
        "<th>Col G</th><th>Col H</th><th>Col I</th>" & _
        "<th>Col J</th><th>Col K</th></tr>" & vbCrLf

    For Each rw In tblRng.Rows
       s = s & "<tr>"
       For Each cell In rw.Cells
          s = s & "<td>" & cell & "</td>"
       Next
       s = s & "</tr>" & vbCrLf
    Next
    RangetoHTML = pre & "<table cellspacing=""0"" cellpadding=""3"" border=""1"">" & _
                  s & "</table>" & vbCrLf

End Function
```